# MariaDB, SEQUENCE engine, dynamic upper bound

Tags: mysql, mariadb, subquery, sequence

I'd like to generate a sequence in MariaDB starting at 1 and ending with whatever is the largest id in some other table. That other table has roughly this schema:

```
create table main (
  id integer primary key,
  -- ... other columns --
);
```

I've learned about [MariaDB *STORAGE* engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sequence-storage-engine/) for generating sequences but on the surface that's good only for generating *static* sequences, where you know the range at the time of writing the query, e.g.

```
MariaDB [skynetdb]> select * from seq_1_to_3;
+-----+
| seq |
+-----+
|   1 |
|   2 |
|   3 |
+-----+
3 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

But how do I generate sequence whose upper bound is the result of `select max(id) from main`? It seems that MariaDB doesn't accept *meta-queries* where I would construct a name of a table to query and then query it in a single query, e.g. something like this:

```
-- INVALID, FOR ILLUSTRATION ONLY
select * from concat('seq_1_to_', select max(id) from main)
```

Or is it possible? How? (Note I'm aware that I can do one additional roundtrip and construct the sequence table name on the client, but I want to avoid it because I don't have a feature rich client, only `mysql` command)

---

The following recursive common table expression (CTE) works

```
MariaDB [skynetdb]> with recursive nums(n) as (select 1 union all select n+1 from nums where n <= (select max(id) from main)) select * from nums;
```

but it's too slow. It seems it constructs whole `nums` table in memory first.

Comment: You can use a prepared statement that concatenates strings first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT seq
    FROM seq_0_to_99999999
    WHERE seq BETWEEN 12345678 and 12345688;
```

works fine and *fast*.  It returned 11 rows.

A more complex query:

```
SELECT MIN(FROM_DAYS(seq)) AS first_day,
       MAX(FROM_DAYS(seq)) AS last_day,
       COUNT(*) AS number_of_days
    FROM seq_0_to_99999999
    WHERE seq BETWEEN TO_DAYS('2020-01-01')
                  AND TO_DAYS(CURDATE());
```

Returned:

```
+------------+------------+----------------+
| first_day  | last_day   | number_of_days |
+------------+------------+----------------+
| 2020-01-01 | 2020-04-02 |             93 |
+------------+------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

It, too, was *fast*, and touched only 94 rows according to the 'Handler_read%' values.  Cf: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts

For your case, you may need something like

```
WHERE seq BETWEEN ...
              AND ( SELECT MAX(...) FROM ... )
```

I find that the general use of seq is to generate a generous number of values, then let `WHERE` go for the range I need.  The Optimizer avoids really generating the zillion values I seem to be asking for.  (At least in examples like these.)